# bad allocation of memory error with bigger data

Tags: c++, vector, size, allocation

I have a vector that contains elements of structure:

```
    struct hairParticle{
        bool seed;
        double mass;
        double diameter;
        double stiffnessCoeff;
        double bendingCoeff;
        double frictionCoeff;
        glm::vec3 position;  
        glm::vec3 velocity;  
        glm::vec3 force;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> direction;
        std::vector<unsigned int> neighbours;
        std::vector<double> neighbourRestingLengths;
    };
```

When I try to populate this vector with data, it works fine with about 1000 entries, but with about 3000 the program crashes with bad allocation of memory.
I don't know what can cause this.After some googling I found this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13653/

and computer says that size of this struct is 120 bytes, presumably without accounting for the size of internal vectors, but for now their size is no more than 10 elements. So even with 200 bytes for each of 3000 elements, the maximum memory 4GB should be enough.

The other solution was to use deque instead of vector, but as I understand it (perhaps wrongly), the deque is not that suitable for indexing and I really need to be able to access any element as fast as possible.

Although I will need to change the internal vectors, I think they are stored in struct as a pointer, which means that the whole vector (of these struct elements) should not need to reallocate memory after the internal vectors are changed (again maybe I'm wrong about this).

I am using Code::Blocks on windows.

Does anyone have an idea, what causes this error and how can I fix it - I would like to keep vector as a container, but do not insist :)
Thanks

Comment: How large are each of the vectors at the bottom of the structure?

Comment: Why do you think your program can actually allocate 4GB of memory?  On Windows you get 2GB of address space by default, 3 with a compiler flag and an OS setting.

Comment: @Mats Peterson Thanks, this error I get is, actually, during the initialization phaze, where vector direction is of size 1, and both neighbours and neighbourDirections are size 2. Looking at my code I realized that I could actually reserve a space for whole vector, which I did and it worked for more elements, but certainly not more than a million, it couldn't go through 50 000.

Comment: @Ed S. Thank you. Actually I don't know, why I thought that the program can allocate all 4GB. I was under the impression, that when the memory is available and the virtual memory maximum usage is set to 4GB, then the program would use it. Anyway, after doing some tests I discovered that the program stopped working when taking up 2GB, so you were right about the program using only 2GB. Can you, please, tell me how can I increase it?

Comment: If your program is using 2GB with 50K elements of "no more than 200 bytes", then there's probably something else using a fair bit of memory - although it could be fragmentation of the heap as well. Of course, assuming your machine actually has more than about 4GB of ram, in a 64-bit system,  you could simply tell your code that it's "/LARGEADDRESSAWARE" in the linking stage. That will tell the allocation code in the kernel that it can use more than 2GB of address space, and you get about 4GB, which will probably make a decent difference. Or just compile it as 64-bit code...

Comment: @Mats Peterson Thanks, you were right about something else going wrong. I finally figured it out. In the initialization phase, while populating the vector, I used a temporary variable, which then I pushed back to the vector. In this temporary variable I had also a vector direction, and what I did not realize was that each time I pushed back the new direction, it was added to the previous instead what I wanted - to have just one element. Simple direction.clear() did it. It is working now, so thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

```
struct hairParticle{
    bool seed;              // 8 bytes
    double mass;
    double diameter;
    double stiffnessCoeff;
    double bendingCoeff;
    double frictionCoeff;    // 5 * 8 = 40 bytes 
    glm::vec3 position;      // 12 bytes?
    glm::vec3 velocity;      // 12 bytes?
    glm::vec3 force;         // 12 bytes?
    std::vector<glm::vec3> direction;   // About 12 or 24 bytes? 
    std::vector<unsigned int> neighbours;   // about 12 or 24 bytes
    std::vector<double> neighbourRestingLengths;// about 12 or 24 bytes
};
```

On a 32-bit machine that structure in itself will take about 120 bytes, yes.

But you will also, presumably store things in the vectors at bottom of the structures, which takes up extra memory.

I should also point out that if you are using Windows, the memory limit for an application in 32-bit mode is 2GB (unless you have jumped through hoops). A 32-bit application that enables "Large address aware" can extend that to 3GB on a 32-bit version of windows, or just under 4GB in a 64-bit version of windows. In Linux the limit is about 3GB.

But even then, you should be able to fit a good number more than 3000 of objects that are somewhere between 120 and 200 bytes in size. In fact, more than a million 200 byte objets shouldn't be ANY problem in the memory available. However, if each object has a load of extra data attached to it, it will obviously add up.

I completely agree that your structure should fit in memory, so I'm pretty sure that it is something else (such as the neighbours and direction elements) that take up a lot of space.

And yes, before someone mentions this in a comment, this is not a proper answer. Because there isn't enough information available in the question to give a proper answer... I just wanted to write something that discusses the issue, and it didn't really fit in a comment...

Comment: Hi, I think I have partially answered your question in the previous comment, but there is some additional info: Code::Blocks is 32-bit, windows 7 64-bit. I'll be happy to provide any additional information.